# Eloquent creating empty record

Tags: laravel

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what it is.
In a controller I have a method which executes:

```
$estimate = Estimate::create(
  ['session_id' => 'test']
);
```

Model:
use HasFactory;

```
protected $fillable = ['width, height, direction_id, media_id, coating_id, shape_id, amount, qty, session_id'];
```

Estimate is related to estimates in my db.
When triggered an estimate record is created but the field 'session_id' is blank.

```
session_id is a VARCHAR 191.
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you show model code also

Comment: Is `session_id` in `fillable`?

Comment: protected $fillable = ['width, height, ..., session_id'];

Should be with ' characters:
protected $fillable = ['width', 'height', ..., 'session_id'];

Comment: protected $fillable = ['width', 'height', 'direction_id', 'media_id', 'coating_id','shape_id', 'amount', 'qty, session_id'];  issue is you have treated all fieds as string but its array .so need to quote each column as string

Comment: ref :https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your `$fillable` wrong. It should be an array of strings:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'width',
    'height',
    'direction_id',
    'media_id',
    'coating_id',
    'shape_id',
    'amount',
    'qty',
    'session_id',
];
```